# cron jobs change time after DST

Tags: unix, shell

My cron job is running an hour later after end of DST.  This didn't happen to other user's jobs on the same machine (AIX).  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first thing to find out is the timezone that cron is running under:

0 1 * * *    (/usr/bin/date ; /usr/bin/date -u) > ~/cron.out

You might also want to get one of the users whose cron jobs are working to do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are converting UTC into local time(correctly) and the job is for a non-DST timezone, like Arizona, it will run an hour later, relative to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already checked this, but was the time changed correctly on the server?

Comment: yes, the time changed on the server. The run-time of my job is changed relative to the server.

Comment: So, you're saying the time of the cron jobs changed to 1 hour later when the time changed?